# Find two hard to reverse functions f and h such that f ∘ h ∘ g = h (f and h injective, no constraints on g)

Tags: hash, aes, homomorphic-encryption, bijection

I am looking from 3 functions $f,g,h$ from $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ (they can be bijections, they need to be injective at least), such that:

$$f \circ  h \circ g = h $$

and $f$ is hard to reverse programmatically, and $h$ is hard to reverse programmatically.

$g$ and $h$ cannot be keyed functions as they will be public.

Right now, I am using [AES SP 801-108](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-108r1.pdf) for $h$ but any function hard to reverse will do.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.se Are you obligated to Block ciphers? What is the origin of this question?

Comment: A block cipher is _"hard to reverse programmatically"_ for one not knowing the key. The [current question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/109569/5) thus seems to allow the following straightforward construction. Note $E_k$ for AES encryption with key $k$, $D_k$ for the decryption. Pick two random secret distinct keys $k,ℓ$ and define $f=E_k∘D_ℓ$, $g=D_k∘E_ℓ$, $h=E_k$. It follows $f∘h∘g=E_k∘D_ℓ∘E_k∘D_k∘E_ℓ=E_k=h$. If this does not fit, please edit the question again; like, if the internals of some function must be public, and it or other function(s) must still be hard to reverse.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Indeed, the internals of function h and g need to be public, therefore only f can be a keyed function. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Please expand on what "hard to reverse" is intended to mean. In particular, does being able to compute $f^{-1}$ count as reversing $f$? If not: what about textbook RSA with a public modulus of secret factorization, $g$ encryption, $f$ decryption, and $h$ encryption with another exponent and the same modulus? That satisfies the equation, and knowing the internals of $g$ and $h$ it's impossible to evaluate $f(x)$, $g^{-1}(x)$ or $h^{-1}(x)$ for random input $x\in[0,p)$. When either $g$, $h$ or $h∘g$ is applied to an appropriately padded message, it can't be deciphered without $f$.

Answer (score 0):

It is essentially key exchange:
let $x$ be the input,
$g$ encrypts $x$ using public key 1, $h$ encrypts the result using public key 2,
and then $f$ decrypts the result using private key 1,
where private key 1 and public key 1 is a public-key pair.
Additionally we need the decryption $f$ cancels $g$ and leaves $h$, which can be obtained from many public-key schemes, such as RSA, suggested by @fgrieu.

The "hard-to-reverse" requirement of $f$ is tricky because the private-key often gives public-key as a simple reverse.
If only $f$ is given, then it might be possible.
This seems impossible if both $f, g$ are publicly given because they mush be dependent (if $f$ is parametered by $k$, then $g$ must depend on $k$).